# How to remove a filename prefix from multiple folders all at once using a batch/command script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to batch remove a prefix in folder names so that these folders:

> [Folder_2009]Folder0001
>
> [Folder_2009]Folder0002
>
> [Folder_2009]Folder0003

will have folder names like these:

> Folder0001
>
> Folder0002
>
> Folder0003

I already found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350344/how-to-delete-first-7-characters-of-folder-name-by-using-batch-script), and while the script works great for files, none works for folders, at least in Windows 10.

I looked around and everything I found was about files and not folders.

Thank you!

Comment: From what I can see there isn't a command for it. The work around is to move the content to a new folder of the name you want, and then delete the old one.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I have over 500 folders with the said prefix so doing it one by one is something I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cmd line

```
for /d %A in ("[*]*") do @for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %B in ("%A") Do @Echo ren "%A" "%C"
```

This will only echo then ren command, to execute remove the echo

In a batch file double the percent signs.

Sample output:

```
> for /d %A in ("[*]*") do @for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %B in ("%A") Do @Echo ren "%A" "%C"
ren "[Folder_2009]Folder0001" "Folder0001"
ren "[Folder_2009]Folder0002" "Folder0002"
ren "[Folder_2009]Folder0003" "Folder0003"
```

Comment: I was under the impression the `ren` didn't work for folders, but I have tested your code and it works for me (although on windows 7)

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked really well.

Comment: @AaronHayman The help `ren /?` is a bit short and ambiguous in that point. For more details read https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html